# content not fully replaced in p tag (with nested h3 tag) on using innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html

I was using innerHTML property in javascript and suddenly I got a problem that the content inside `<p><h3>....</h3></p>` is not being fully replaced when applying `.innerHTML` on `<p>` tag in it. But when I make the same thing in a `<div>` as `<div><h3>....</h3></div>` it fully replaces the inner content. Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

See what's happening in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur3291/udVs4/).

See full code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>innerHTML doubt</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeContent(id){
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Content changed in id '"+id+"'.";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1">
        This content is in first <b>'p'</b> tag (can b fully replaced).
    </p>
    <button onclick="changeContent('p1')">Change upper content</button><hr/>
    <p id="p2">
        <h3>This content is in second 'p' tag with 'h3' tag inside (will not be replaced fully)      </h3>
    </p>
    <button onclick="changeContent('p2')">Change upper content</button><hr/>
    <div id="div1">
        This content is in first 'div' (can b fully replaced).
    </div>
    <button onclick="changeContent('div1')">Change upper content</button><hr/>
    <div id="div2">
        <h3>This content is in second 'div' inside of 'h3'(will also b replaced fully)</h3>
    </div>
    <button onclick="changeContent('div2')">Change upper content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have `h3` inside `p`. That's why it happens.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200227/h1-h2-h3-tags-inline-within-paragraphs-p). In a similar way, the OP is trying to put `header` tags inside `p` tags, which is not allowed - similarly stated by @dfsq.

Comment: @dfsq: even I was also thinking the same but how can this be the reason for it? `h3` is working fine inside `p` and `.innerHTML` just needs to replace the content inside though whatever it is, isn't it?

Comment: All I can say, you can't expect browsers to handle correctly situation when you act against spec which vendors based their browsers on. And standards clears say "don't put block elements inside p".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because when you use `<h3></h3>` or any heading tag within `p` tag ,the closing tag gets out of scope.

Error when i validate code at [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org)

[image: Error on validation]

---

**[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/udVs4/2/)**.In this fiddle you will see that in 2nd `p` only the text outside and before `<h3></h3>` will be replaced by innerHTML.That means `<p>` gets closed before `<h3></h3>` because using **h3** within **p** is *invalid*.

### Only solution

Use CSS style similar to `h3` for styling text inside `p` tags.**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/udVs4/4/)**

Comment: got it!...the header tag separates the start tag `<p>` and the end tag `</p>`, they are no more combined to each other.....thanks!..:)