# jQuery html() function stops when it sees a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use html() to read in the content between two tags.  Note the content itself may include tags nested inside.
I have tried html(), innerHTML, clone() and all of them have the same problem ... if I try to read in something like

```
<p id="firstnote>Today is <h1>Monday</h1>. Someone has a case of the
Mondays.</p>
```

It should read into a string

```
var string = "Today is <h1>Monday</h1>. Someone has a case of the Mondays."
```

including the h1 tag.  What I get is
"Today is "

It's not even an issue with a child element (I don't think) because it won't return the ". Someone has a case of the Mondays." part.

I've tried the trick of creating a temporary div and appending but I get the same problem - ultimately extracting out the code between the tags ignores everything including and after the initial inline <
Here is the js

```
function parseblog () {
var blogarray = ["", "", "", ""];

$.get('blogtest.html', function(data) {
//Read blogs into array
blogarray[0] = $(data).find('#notes').html();
blogarray[1] = $(data).find('#firstblog').html();
blogarray[2] = $(data).find('#secondblog').html();
blogarray[3] = $(data).find('#thirdblog').html();

alert(blogarray[0]);
alert(blogarray[1]);
});}
```

The HTML for testing

```
<div id="blog">
<h1 id="notes">Notes</h1>
<p id="firstblog">Monday February 23, 2015<h2>10:56am</h2>Another try</p>
<p id="secondblog">Hello World!</p>
<p id="thirdblog"></p>
</div>
```

The first alert gives me Notes.  The second alert gives me Monday February 23, 2015

Answer (score 3):

[Headers inside paragraphs is invalid.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200251/3187556) Your HTML is being parsed as such:

```
<p id="firstnote">Today is </p>
<h1>Monday</h1>
. Someone has a case of the Mondays.
<p></p>
```

(each line is its own node)

Then, jQuery's `.html()` only returns the HTML of the first element in the matched set. In this case, that's the first `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid HTML. You can not have a `h#` tag inside of a paragraph element. The browser will change the HTML so it is valid. When it encounters the H2, it closes the paragraph tag.

Description From MDN:

> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>`
>   element is immediately followed by an `<address>, <article>, <aside>,
>   <blockquote>, <div>, <dl>, <fieldset>, <footer>, <form>, <h1>, <h2>,
>   <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <header>, <hr>, <menu>, <nav>, <ol>, <pre>,
>   <section>, <table>, <ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no
>   more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an
>   `<a>` element.

Paragraphs can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Answer (score 0):

You have a headline tag inside a paragraph tag.
Here's how I might write your test code.  It adds a few more tags so the code is a bit more legible:

```
<div id="blog">
<h1 id="notes">Notes</h1>
<div id="firstblog">
<p class="date">Monday February 23, 2015</p>
<h2>10:56am</h2>
<p class="content">Another try</p>
</div> <!-- End of "firstblog" tag -->

<p id="secondblog">Hello World!</p>
<p id="thirdblog"></p>
</div> <!-- end of "blog" tag -->
```