# css - is there a way to have div on the same second line with h1 (multiple lines)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this:

```
<h1><span>Test Heading This is text that I want to make appear to the right This is text that I want to make appear to the right This is text that I want</span></h1> 
<div>This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line. This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line.  </div>
```

Here is the style:

```
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: calibri, arial;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
h1 span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #446688;
    padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Is there a way to have div on the same second line with h1 (multiple lines)

https://jsfiddle.net/tarjoadi/w5q6qqLv/

This is want I want to be:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaan.png)

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you want it to render as with your description.

Comment: You probably need to make an image of what you're trying to achieve. As epascarello said, it's not clear from your description or your fiddle.

Comment: I added width:50% to your jsfiddle h1 css tag and got the desired effect

Comment: I just updated the question with a screenshot of what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to align both chunks of text on the same line, you just need to make them both 'inline'. To do this just apply the css style: `display: inline;`

You also need to remove `float: left;`, otherwise you will probably not get the result you are after.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #446688;
    /* float: left; */
}

/* New styles */
h1, div.inline {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Test Heading This is text</span></h1> 
<div class="inline">This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using `h1` tag.

```css
.bb {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}
p span {
  font-family: calibri, arial;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #446688;
  padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Test Heading This is text that I want to make appear to the right This is text that I want to make appear to the right This is text that I want</span>
  This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line. This is text that I want to make appear to the right of the heading and above the blue base line.
</p>
```

Similar question: [<h1>, <h2>, <h3>... tags, inline within paragraphs (<p>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200227/h1-h2-h3-tags-inline-within-paragraphs-p)

Comment: can you please give me a solution for <h1>? I need to use h1 for SEO