# Django 1.10 Template Renders Nested HTML Tags Outside Their Parent

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I am a bit puzzled by the following behavior of the Django templates, which prevents me from successfully styling the output.

Namely, I have the following template:

```
<article class="article
    {% if article.is_featured %} featured{% endif %}
    {% if not article.published %} unpublished{% endif %}">
{% if not detail_view %}

    <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="{% namespace_url 'article-detail' article.slug namespace=namespace default='' %}">
            <h2 class="post-title">
           {% render_model article "title" "" "" "striptags" %}
            </h2>
           {% if article.lead_in %}
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {% if not detail_view %}
                    {% render_model article "lead_in" "" "" "truncatewords:'20'|striptags" %}
                {% else %}    
                    {% render_model article "lead_in" "" "" "striptags" %}
                {% endif %}
            </h3>
           {% endif %}
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> Posted by 
            {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/author.html" with author=article.author %}
            on {{ article.publishing_date|date:"F d, Y" }}
        </p> 
        <p class="post-meta" style="margin: 0">
            <h4 style="display:inline-flex">Categories:</h4>
                {% for category in article.categories.all %}
                    <a href="/articles/category/{{category.name|lower}}">{{ category.name }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}</a>
                {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p class="post-meta" style="margin: 0">
            <h4 style="display:inline-flex">Tags:</h4>
                {% for tag in article.tag %}
                    <a href="/articles/category/{{tag.name|lower}}">{{ tag.name }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}</a>
                {% endfor %}
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr>
{% endif %}

{% if detail_view %}
<!--    <h3>Testing template! (from article with detail_view=True)</h3> -->
        {% render_placeholder article.content language placeholder_language %}        
{% endif %}

</article>
```

The output of this template is roughly like this:

```
<article class="article">
    <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="/articles/third-post/">
            <h2 class="post-title">
           Third Post
            </h2>  
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                    Third post lead-in text.
            </h3>
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> Posted by 
    <a href="">      
    </a>

            on September 19, 2017
        </p> 
        <p class="post-meta" style="margin: 0">
            <h4 style="display:inline-flex">Categories:</h4>

             <a href="/articles/category/programming">Programming </a>               
        </p>
    <p class="post-meta" style="margin: 0">
        <h4 style="display:inline-flex">Tags:</h4>

    </p>

    </div>
    <hr>
</article>
```

Although the source HTML seems correct, the browser treats it as the following image illustrates.

[image: As you can see, the H4 tag and others are taken outside the <p> tag.]

What am I missing? Is the template incorrect? Or is this a bug I am observing? I tried this in Safari and Firefox. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is just the browser dev tools trying to make sense of your invalid HTML.

An `h` element cannot go inside a `p` element.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:

[<h1>, <h2>, <h3>... tags, inline within paragraphs (<p>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200227/h1-h2-h3-tags-inline-within-paragraphs-p)

They explain it in depth more in there but basically your `<h1,2,3,4>` tags being embedded in the `<p>` tags is considered illegal by the browser and is automatically closing the tags.  Use a different tag and it should fix your problem.

Comment: Much appreciated!